# Where SUM(table1.field) >= table2.field in joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, group-by

I am using codeigniter. I want a where clause to get the products where totalQuantity is less than alterQuantity. I am using sum in select clause to get totalQuantity.

```
$this->db->select("products.id as productid, products.code, products.name, products.unit, products.cost, products.price, sum(whs_products.quantity) as totalQuantity, products.alert_quantity as alertQuantity")
->from('products')
->where('alertQuantity <=', 'totalQuantity')
->join('whs_products', 'whs_products.product_id=products.id', 'left')
->group_by("products.id");
$this->db->get();
```

I am not sure how to get the desired products :(
EDIT
if tried this

```
->where('alertQuantity <=', 'totalQuantity')
```

I get all the products but with ->where('alertQuantity <=', 'totalQuantity') no products.

Comment: I think you want to use `HAVING`, not `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add FALSE in your select statement and try

```
$this->db->select("products.id as productid, products.code, products.name, products.unit, products.cost, products.price, sum(whs_products.quantity) as totalQuantity, products.alert_quantity as alertQuantity",FALSE)
```

> $this->db->select() accepts an optional second parameter. If you set
>   it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select
>   statement.

From document [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select)

Comment: Thank you LearneR. I already tried this bit I have keep getting all the products :( Is left join ok here? I am not sure about join

Comment: put where condition after the join

Comment: Tired But Same  if tried this

->where('alertQuantity <=', 'totalQuantity')

I get all the products but with ->where('alertQuantity <=', 'totalQuantity') no products.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id AS productid, p.code, p.name, p.unit, p.cost, p.price, wp.quantity AS totalQuantity, p.alert_quantity AS alertQuantity
FROM products p 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) quantity 
              FROM whs_products GROUP BY product_id) wp ON wp.product_id = p.id AND p.alert_quantity <= quantity ;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$this->db->select("products.id as productid, products.code, products.name, products.unit, products.cost, products.price, sum(whs_products.quantity) as totalQuantity, products.alert_quantity as alertQuantity")
->from('products')
->join('whs_products', 'whs_products.product_id=products.id', 'left')
->where('alertQuantity <= totalQuantity')
->group_by("products.id");
$this->db->get();

echo $this->db->last_query();exit; //to check the query generated is  correct or not
```